# How would I add text to top navigation?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I have a top navigation bar which allows the user to go back. I managed to changed the colour but i dont understand how i could add text to it. In the code you can see how i added colour but how would i add text.

[image: Screenshot]

```
 NavigationPage navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage());
            navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#52D246");
            navigationPage.BarTextColor = Color.White;

            MainPage = navigationPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `Title` property of the `ContentPage`

```
NavigationPage navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage()
  {
    Title = "Nav Text Here";
  }
);
```

Comment: Do you know how i could add the top navigation to other pages.

Answer (score -1):

```
navigationPage.Title = "Page title";
```